# Can we use GeoExt Freely?

Tags: open-source-gis, geoext

I want to know, can we use GeoExt freely? is there any need to purchase some license for using GeoExt ?

Actually i am already working with free Open source tools (OpenLayers+GeoServer) for my webMap applications. But i need some specific functionality which is possible with GeoExt. so can i use GeoExt freely with Openlayers and GeoServer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoExt is available under BSD, but ExtJS, on which GeoExt depends, is not free for commercial use and has to be purchased.

Comment: Ext is free for commercial use, so long as you can adhere to the terms of the GPL. If you can not (Or don't want to figure out if you can), you can purchase commercial licenses.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the site:

> GeoExt is available under the BSD
>   license and is supported by a growing
>   community of individuals, businesses
>   and organizations.

BSD License Details can be found here: [BSD License](http://www.linfo.org/bsdlicense.html)  or at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses)

Edit (thanks to Petr, I completely forgot about ExtJS):
In short, the answer is yes for personal, no for commercial due to [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/license/) licensing.  ExtJS is licensed through the GPLv3 license.

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that. For example, you should be able to use it on a company internal web-site without issue. But, it's best to avoid GPL Javascript libraries for public web-site if only for the headache in figuring out what is permissible.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132519-Can-I-use-ExtJS-library-freely-in-my-commercial-products