# Webmap app using geoserver must have source code open?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, web-mapping, geoext, license

We have a Webmap that uses geoserver + geoExt + openLayers. Even though the JavaScript code is not obfuscated or compressed, at the moment we do not intend to have a place were someone can got and download our website "source code". A friend said that since we use GPL software, we must make the source code available. Now, I believe the use of geoserver, geoExt, openLayers (with its licenses GPL, FreeBSD, BSD) does not enforce me to distribute our webmap source code, is that correct? Or am I understanding GPL wrong?

I'm basing my understanding in two sentences, one from GPL FAQ and another from Drupal FAQ.

> From GPL FAQ: If I know someone has a copy of a GPL-covered program,
>   can I demand he give me a copy? No. The GPL gives him permission to
>   make and redistribute copies of the program if he chooses to do so. He
>   also has the right not to redistribute the program, if that is what he
>   chooses.
>
> From Drupal FAQ: 11: Do I have to give the code for my web site to
>   anyone who visits it?
>
> No. The GPL does not consider viewing a web site to count as
>   "distributing", so you are not required to share the code running on
>   your server.

Comment: I think that only the OpenLayers and geoExt licences are the issue.

Comment: especially http://trac.geoext.org/wiki/license see also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/can-we-use-geoext-freely